# Change the color of the omitted newline char in fish shell

Tags: fish

Is there any way to change the color of the "⏎" sign after output of `echo -n a` (or any command which doesn't have `\n` at the end of the result)?

It's unreadable if using black background.

[image: screenshot]

There is an enter mark after `->`, but it's hard to find it.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way at present to change the color of that character. See the `omitted_newline_char` symbol in the src/screen.cpp source. It is currently hardcoded to what should be a light grey color visible on most terminals. You're welcome to open an enhancement request. Even better would be to submit a change for review that makes this configurable without breaking the current behavior.